# How can I "fake" the axis ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot in `matplotlib` that looks like this:
[image]

I also have a different plot that looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do is create a plot that looks like this:
[image]

That is, I want to keep the data points exactly where they are in the first plot, but replace the x axis ticks and labels with the ones from the second plot. (In this case they are generated with `plt.xscale('symlog')`.) I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do this. Is there one?

Note: it shouldn't really need saying, but the plot in this question isn't my actual plot, and I do have a reason to want to do this. I'm happy to clarify the question I'm asking, but I don't think it's helpful to ask for the details of why I need it. The question is about how to do the specific thing I've asked how to do, and on-topic responses are appreciated.

Comment: can you just use `set_xticklabels([])` on the first plot and then add a second plot with the scale you want and no data?

Comment: @Andrew possibly?... in that case, how would I hide the axes of the first plot and make the second plot overlap the first one instead of being displayed separately?

Comment: Why don't you just apply a simple transformation to all your points? This seems easier than hacking the axes labels...

Comment: In which regard? Performance? Could you include some information about your real use case in the question?

Comment: I agree that I can't see a good reason for doing this (your scale won't have any meaning in the context of the data, so why bother with it at all?). A second call to the same `Axes` object and manual setting of the tick positions and labels should work. Alternatively you could just use `annotate` and determine the positions you need for the labels

Comment: @Felix the required transformation is not actually that simple. It consists of `np.pow(some_constant,my_x_data)*np.sign(my_x_data)`, but the problem is that the value of `some_constant` depends on the automatic scaling chosen by matplotlib.

Comment: @Nathaniel So you're saying that your data (the tick value accociated with a data point) depends on how it's displayed? That sounds weird. I think it would be helpful if you could show a small example of that in your question.

Comment: @Felix no, my data doesn't depend on how it's displayed. I think if you try to implement the transformation you mentioned, you will quickly realise what I meant and see why it's true. I don't want to spend more time explaining it, because it's not actually relevant to the question.

Comment: @Nathaniel In this case, I don't want to spend more time investigating this question then. Even after your edits and comments, it's still not clear to me what the requirements of a solution to your *real* problem are. I hope that your question is clear to someone else, but I doubt it.

Comment: There is [an example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/custom_scale_example.html) about custom scales. What more information do you need?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that example shows how to create a custom scale, but I'm asking how to use a stock scale (the one provided by `symlog`) but without changing where the data points are drawn. Those are related tasks, but not the same.

Comment: So 0 should be in the middle, independent of the original data? And then what axis limits are desired. I feel the question still lacks some information to be answered.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, `symlog` puts 0 in the middle, assuming the axis limits are symmetric. The desired axis limits are variables in my code. I'd be happy to clarify the question but honestly I've lost enthusiasm for it given the previous comments. (Not yours.) If I can't figure it out tonight I might do that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem in the future, here's a solution that works. I don't know if it's the best way.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

# use ax1 to plot the data

ax1.axes("off")
ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax1.get_position())
ax2.patch.set_alpha(0)

# then do whatever you want to set up the axes of ax2. In my case:

ax1_xlim = ax1.get_xlim()
ax2.set_xlim([-np.power(10,-ax1_xlim[0]), np.power(10,ax1_xlim[1])])
```

I do not understand why all the comments and other answers were so focused on the 'why' of this simple task. I hope this will be helpful to others in spite of all the noise.

Answer (score 1):

I looks to me that this question asks for a workaround in order to avoid transforming the data to the desired scale. This should be pretty straight forward by applying the inverse function to the data before plotting. Yet, there is not enough information given in the question as to what the problem would be for such solution.

---

Therefore one can only answer the question as it is; this basically translates into creating a completely unrelated axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.random.rand(2,30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, ls="", marker="+")

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xscale("symlog")
ax2.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", bottom=True, labelbottom=True, 
                top=False, labeltop=False)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
ax2.set_xlim(-50,50)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here the x limits are chosen arbitrarily. The problem will be to relate the limits to the original data. Due to a 5% default margin on both sides, this will in general not be trivial and any function doing this task will become much more complicated than a function computing the inverse transform on the original data.

Comment: Actually you are wrong. There is enough information in the question. You asked for more clarification and I edited the question to provide it. I would have been happy to provide more if you asked, and in fact I promised to do so tomorrow. What on Earth is wrong with this community?

Comment: You answered my question about the limits by saying you have that function available. But I don't. Hence this is what I can provide given the information at hand. In how far is it not what you're after?

Comment: Your answer is perfectly good. The downvote is for the completely pointless and self-evidently false claim that I didn't include enough information.

Comment: This is not a diss, it's kind of a warning for future readers that this is an xyproblem and there might in fact be better options available.

Comment: I answered the `Y` in the xyproblem. I commented about the `X` requiring more information.

Comment: I mean, if someone wants to replace the x ticks of one plot with the x ticks from another plot, then, obviously, either they know what the relationship is between the data of the first plot and the tick marks of the second, or their use case is such that it doesn't matter. This is not an XY question. It's just a question.

Comment: Correct. If they know the relationship, they can apply the inverted relationship to the data before plotting and use the desired scale directly. (That's what the first part of the answer says) If the relationship doesn't matter, one wouldn't ask for a symlog scale in the first place.

Comment: I read the question essentially as "I want a fully functional x-axis completely unrelated to my data". For this, there was enough information given. Transforming might result in extra computation time or another problem (not every function is invertible). I can understand, that one might want a more beautiful solution, but I think this answers the question perfectly +1

Comment: @Importance that's just a failure of your imagination. The inverted transformation might not be so straightforward to calculate (as indeed is the case for the `symlog` scale, as I already explained in the comments). Or the author might feel that applying a transformation to the data rather than the axes would violate the principle of least surprise, should they have to understand their code again in six months' time. Alternatively, one might ask for a symlog scale in cases where the plot is simply an illustrative one, not displaying real data. In that case the exact scale wouldn't matter.

Comment: The point is, there are plenty of reasons why one would ask this question, and it's completely irrelevant which of them is the case for me. This was a simple question. I don't get why it warranted all the weird criticism.

Comment: If you are interested in feedback about why your question was received in the way observed here, you can ask a question about on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). The short answer is: Always disclose your motivation (similar to how you cannot publish a paper in science without a clear motivation).

Comment: @Nathaniel: You downvote the answers given by people to your question? Really?

Comment: @Bazingaa not as a rule, no, but I did in this case. The XY criticism is an irrelevant waste of my time, so I don't see why I shouldn't use the very minor sanction available to me.

Comment: @Nathaniel Honestly, I do not have any hard feelings against anyone and I do not care about a downvote, but your last comment is pretty inappropriate. Your question consumed several peoples' time. Complaining about someone giving feedback, asking for clarifications and writing answers in a way to prevent future readers from falling for a not so great solution is the wrong attitude here. Also mind that voting is no sactionning mechanism.

Comment: I was pretty clear both in the question itself and in the comment thread that I don't consider the XY discussion a helpful one. I'm not complaining that you asked for feedback, I'm complaining that after I took the time to give it, you ignored it. Your answer warrants a downvote because the first paragraph is unhelpful.

Comment: Even if only chapters 4 to 6 of a book are useful for me, I wouldn't blame the author of having written the other chapters. This is all a question of attitude.

Comment: You are lucky that ImportanceOfBeingEarnest didn’t use his/her major sanction (Gold badge) available to him/her because your question had no attempt included, no code, no data. Such questions could have been straightforwardly closed by him/her for being too broad or for not including any code. So you should be highly thankful to him/her for not doing that and instead answering you

Comment: @Bazingaa I didn't need to include those things in the question, because it was a simple question and did in fact contain enough information for it to be answered. We know this because it has in fact been answered, so continuing to believe this is impossible would constitute a rather strange failure of logic. If Importance cares about the downvote (they said they don't) then the appropriate response wouldn't be to abuse the close vote system but to remove the first paragraph, or even just soften the wording, in which case it would become a +1 and a green tick. I think Importance knows this.

Comment: You can always "soften the wording" yourself by [edit]ing. If you rather moan about a problem than solving it, there might be better places than stackoverflow.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest probably the amount by which I care about the downvote is rather less than the amount by which you care about it. As I said, *if* you care about it, *then you* can edit it. Otherwise I think we're done here, aren't we?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply set the labels of the xticks like this.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), [10, 10^2, 10^5])
```

Answer (score 0):

ImportanceOfBeingErnest said this is a rescaling problem, and I agree with him.

**General principle**

From what I understood, your are trying to do something like :

1. Plot your function with 'vanilla' unit  =>  y = f(x)
2. Express the x axis in another unit      =>  x [unit] = x' [deg]
3. Plot your function with new unit        =>  y = f(x')
4. Choose nice xlim to have the point at the 'same location' as before (see ImportanceOfBeingErnest answer)

**NB** : you can write x' = g(x) another function and then have y = f ( g(x) )
All you need to know is this g function in order to rescale.

I repeat, **I see this problem as a unit change problem**. So the answer depends on the problem, its nature, its parameters. This is what hidden behind this g function.

**Nearly the answer you need**

In your case, according to the plot you shown, I can give you an approximate answer :

x' = 10 * ( x - 0.5)

np.semilogx(x',y)

0.5 because the new 0 seems to be where you had 0.5. I substract in order to center the new points in 0.5.
10 * because you transform 0.1 into 10^0.

Comment: imho: Why bother with thinking about a transformation, when you can just throw another axis in, that does exactly what you want? What is the benefit one gets from the extra work?

Comment: Indeed you can also work on axis and don't touch the data, but this is the same approach. Indeed anyway you will have to calculate the transformation from one axis to the other. Either you transform data, or transform axis, but the conversion is the same. Nevertheless if you don't do science, you can do whatever you want and put irrelevant numbers just for any purpose or whatever. There is a function to force xtickslabels.